# VS Code error: Import "pyomo.environ" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyomo

I'm getting the error

> Import "pyomo.environ" could not be resolved
> Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I used to get the same issue with numpy but now only Pyomo is having an issue. I have tried everything online and have not found a solution.

I have tried adding possible Paths to `extrapaths` in Pylance since I'm assuming that's where the problem is. The directories I added are exactly where Pyomo shows up. I am using Python 3.10 and that is where all my other site-packages are that work and only Pyomo gives me an issue. I've tried re-installing everything associated and I'm not sure why it won't recognize.

Comment: So, don't delete it, then. You gave Stack Exchange the right to distribute the question when you posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the issue, but I did find a work-around where pyomo errors weren't necessary where I could run the python file without errors preventing it from running. Having the additional Python extensions in VSCode I had uninstalled so the Pylance Error wouldn't come up and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Pyomo is installed and available in your Python environment.  Run `pip list` in your terminal and see a list of all installed packages.

If Pyomo is not listed, you can install it by running `pip install pyomo`.

Comment: yes it shows up in pip list

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the **correct** interpreter for vscode.

*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python:Select Interpreter*

[image]

Verify your output interpreter with the following code.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You can also use the obtained full path to install `pyomo`

[image]